# Oracle SQL non-unique table alias in one Select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, alias

Does somebody know why this works with both table alias "x"?

```
Select x.company_name  
      ,x.employee_name 
FROM company  x
JOIN employee x ON x.company_id = 5
```

I know that the JOIN with id 5 makes no sense...

Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: Is `company_id` a unique column?

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. in my opinon it doesn't matter. i'm wondering why i can use the same alias "x" twice.

Lets say, on company it is unique and on employee not. relation is "company has many employees".

Comment: What I ment was, if the column names (`company_name`, `employee_name` and `company_id`) are unique, so they exist only in one of the two tables, the alias doesn't matter.

Comment: I've written a test case where both tables have `company_id` and query runs fine. I only get an error if I add `x.company_id` to the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two queries below are equivalent. In the `ON` clause of the join the table alias `x` only refers to the last table to use that alias so only the `employee` table is restricted.

In the `SELECT` and `WHERE` expressions the `x` alias refers to both tables - so, where the column names are unique then they can be successfully referenced but where there are identical column names then oracle raises an `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` exception (as happens in query 3 if the comment is removed).

I can't find any documentation on this but it looks very like a bug.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f006c/28)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  company_id    NUMBER(3),
  employee_name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE company (
  company_id    NUMBER(3),
  company_name VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES ( 4, 'Four Emp' );
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ( 5, 'Five Emp' );
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ( 6, 'Six Emp' );

INSERT INTO company VALUES ( 4, 'Four Company' );
INSERT INTO company VALUES ( 5, 'Five Company' );
INSERT INTO company VALUES ( 6, 'Six Company' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   company  x
       JOIN
       employee x
       ON x.company_id = 5
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f006c/28/0)**:

```
| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY_NAME | EMPLOYEE_NAME |
|------------|--------------|---------------|
|          5 | Four Company |      Five Emp |
|          5 | Five Company |      Five Emp |
|          5 |  Six Company |      Five Emp |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   company x
       CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT * FROM employee WHERE company_id = 5) x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f006c/28/1)**:

```
| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY_NAME | EMPLOYEE_NAME |
|------------|--------------|---------------|
|          5 | Four Company |      Five Emp |
|          5 | Five Company |      Five Emp |
|          5 |  Six Company |      Five Emp |
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT --x.company_id,
       x.company_name,
       x.employee_name
FROM   company x
       CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT * FROM employee WHERE company_id = 5) x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f006c/28/2)**:

```
| COMPANY_NAME | EMPLOYEE_NAME |
|--------------|---------------|
| Four Company |      Five Emp |
| Five Company |      Five Emp |
|  Six Company |      Five Emp |
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd lay money on "Oracle bug" - Of all the things that've most held me back from adopting the ANSI JOIN syntax, it's been Oracle's painfully egregious and bug-laden implementation thereof.  That said, "Failure to catch a syntax error" is pretty minor, and Oracle has, as far as I can tell, largely cleaned up their act.

Comment: +1 Looks like a bug to me too.  I found a related bug on My Oracle Support.  It's not the same thing, but it shows that Oracle has had issues with not raising the ambiguous exception: "Bug 5368296 - ANSI join SQL may not report ORA-918 for ambiguous column".  Although even with these (rare) ANSI syntax bugs I think the ANSI syntax is still well worth it.  I'll gladly accept an Oracle bug once a year if I can avoid the unorganized (+) syntax.

Comment: Not all bugs are created equal.  When a bug with ANSI join causes a crucial query to get subtly wrong reults, runs in production for 2 weeks before notice, and results in data corruption that takes 4-weeks to cleanup ... not the best feeling in the world to be the guy who'd argued for widespread adoption of the cleaner syntax there...